# Get rid of jQuery for .css() modification and use AngularJS directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, element

I am using an angularJS directive to get full-height elements, and it's working great. The problem is that I load the whole jQuery library just for using it once : on the `$(element)`.

I've been playing around with `angular.element` or `element[0]` or event `angular.element(element[0])` but I cannot make it work. The element appears undefined or nothing happens at all.

We should be able to select that element right ? Here's my code. Thanks a lot

```
app.directive('fullHeight', ['$window', function ($window) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
        scope.initializeWindowSize = function () {
            $(element).css('min-height', $window.innerHeight);
        };
        scope.initializeWindowSize();
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
            scope.initializeWindowSize();
        });
    }
}; 
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

*I load the whole jQuery library just for using it once*

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.

You don't need to load the library, just use `element`, as it is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches.

```
element.css('min-height', $window.innerHeight);
```

However important note [Angular's jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite)

> `css()` - Only retrieves inline-styles, does not call `getComputedStyle(). As a setter, does not convert numbers to strings or append 'px', and also does not have automatic property prefixing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.style.minHeight = $window.innerHeight`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

element is already wrapped within angular's jqLite. element within the link function in a directive refers to the main wrapper in the template. You can then use element[0].querySelector('selector_here') to get specific elements within.